# Problem with reverse engineering a many-to-one unidirectional association with hibernate tools

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, reverse-engineering, hibernate-tools

I'm using Hibernate tools 3.40 in Eclipse (Helios).
I'm trying to generate POJOs from my DB (MSSQL 2008) with EJB3 style (i.e. JPA2.0 annotations).
Let's say I have two tables `A` and `B` where there is a foreign key from `A` to `B`.
This generates, by default, a POJO for `A` which has `B` as a member (its "parent") and a POJO for `B` which has a `Set<A>` as a member (its "children").
What I'd like is to know how I can control the rev-eng so that only one side of the association is created (I have different use cases so basically all three options are important for me).
I do not want to use hbm.xml files as I'm working with annotations and JPA2.0 but I can specify some metadata on the reverse engineering process to hibernate via hibernae.reveng.xml

I've tried configuring the `foreign-key` attribute and defining there the `exclude=true` but that only provided me with a half an answer for one scenario. That generated an `A` POJO with a bPK int member which is tolerable and understandable **but** the generated POJO of `B` now does not compile as the `one-to-many` annotation has an invalid attribute; The `mappedby="unresolved"` due to the fact that `A` no longer has a property which hibernate reveng can map back to.

So, I currently cannot create uni-directional associations and I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a class for `reveng. strategy` at `Hibernate Code Generation Configuration`

Example :

```
public class MyReverseEngineeringStrategy extends DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy {

   public MyReverseEngineeringStrategy(ReverseEngineeringStrategy delegate) {
       super(delegate);
   }

   @Override
   public void setSettings(ReverseEngineeringSettings settings) {
       super.setSettings(settings);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean excludeForeignKeyAsCollection(String keyname, 
    TableIdentifier fromTable, java.util.List fromColumns, 
    TableIdentifier referencedTable, java.util.List referencedColumns) {

    // TODO : Your work here
    if (keyname.equals("___") && 
        fromTable.getName().equals("___") && 
        fromColumns.contains("___") && 
        referencedTable.getName().equals("___") && 
        referencedColumns.contains("___")) {

        return true;
    }

    return false;
   }
}
```

JavaDoc for method `excludeForeignKeyAsCollection`

```
Should this foreignkey be excluded as a oneToMany
```

and there also have another method call `excludeForeignKeyAsManytoOne`

```
Should this foreignkey be excluded as a many-to-one
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wish there was a better way to do this than to hardcode these requirements in that "obscure" class but at least it's a working solution.

Comment: I have the same problem, but your answer is specific for the "___", it is not a general answer. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Currently (*tested with Hibernate Tools 5.2*), generating unidirectional many-to-one works.

In the documentation (https://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.0.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#hibernaterevengxmlfile), you can see that you can exclude some side of the relationship :

For example (renaming properties)

```
 <!-- control many-to-one and set names for a specific named foreign key constraint -->
 <foreign-key constraint-name="ORDER_CUST">
   <many-to-one property="customer"/>
   <set property="orders"/>
 </foreign-key>
```

Or (excluding properties)

```
 <!-- can also control a pure (shared pk) one-to-one  -->
  <foreign-key constraint-name="ADDRESS_PERSON">
   <one-to-one exclude="false"/>
   <inverse-one-to-one exclude="true"/>
  </foreign-key>
```

So to have just one side of the relationship with @ManyToOne only, you could do the following :

```
<table name="city" schema="public">
    <primary-key property="id">
        <key-column name="id" type="integer"/>
    </primary-key>
</table>

<table name="country" schema="public">
    <foreign-key constraint-name="country_capital_fkey" foreign-schema="public">
        <many-to-one property="capital" exclude="false"/>
        <set exclude="true" />
    </foreign-key>
</table>
```

You can also fetch an instance of my sample database with Docker here :

> docker pull ghusta/postgres-world-db:2.1